# Does Cloudera Navigator Key Trustee Server ,Cloudera Navigator Key HSM , Cloudera Navigator Key Trustee KMS necessary for Impala installation?

Tags: cloudera, impala, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cloudera-navigator

I am installing Impala using Cloudera manager. And they are saying to install

1  Cloudera Navigator Key Trustee Server
2 Cloudera Navigator Key HSM
3  Cloudera Navigator Key Trustee KMS
4  Cloudera Navigator Encrypt

while these installations required enterprise licence. Is it necessary for Impala?

Answer (score 0):

No.  These services are only needed if you want have a highly secure environment, in particular if you want to encrypt your HDFS data.  You can read more about [HDFS Transparent Encryption](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_sg_hdfs_encryption.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba--5a52cca-1476e7473cd--7f85).